# I have to write validation rule on custom object customer as

Tags: validation, salesforce

If city__c is equal to hyd panCard, phone,email blank through error.

Comment: If you're new to writing validation rules, you should start with the relevant module on [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic).

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if i understood your question correctly. Try it with:

```
AND(
city__c = 'hyd panCard',
ISBLANK(phone),
ISBLANK(email)
)
```